# FInding minimum of a binary search tree in Racket

Tags: binary-search-tree, racket

So, i am trying to find the least value of a binary search tree in racket and i keep getting this error:

cadr: contract violation
  expected: (cons/c any/c pair?)
  given: 'null

My code is the following:

(define minimum
  (λ (tree)
    (if (null? tree) null
        (if (null? (cadr tree)) (car tree)
           (minimum (cadr tree)))))

Each node has the structure (value, left, right).

Comment: Please provide proof that this isn't homework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a problem with your test data, not the `minimum` procedure itself. For instance, this works for me:

```
(define tree
  (list 5 (list 3 (list 1 null null)
                  (list 4 null null))
          (list 6 null null)))

(minimum tree)
=> 1
```